# Yield curve by liquidity premium hypothesis

Tags: finance, quantitative-finance, yield-return, eco

I want to understand the yield curve with the liquidity premium hypothesis. Suppose that the spot rate for one year maturity is 5 per cent. Then the expected future short rates are 5 per cent for each year. In this case, the liquidity premium will be 1 per cent. I was looking at the yield curve. It shows that the yield curve is upward sloping, but after a point, it becomes a straight line. Can someone explain this.

I did try thinking through it. I can understand that it should be upward sloping. But why it becomes constant after a point.

Comment: What does this have to do with programming? You are asking in a programming site.

Comment: You would have to check their help section to see if your question would be on-topic there, but the [quant.se] site might be a better choice for this question.